# How to use a Google Map with polymer?

Tags: google-maps, dart, dart-polymer

I'd like to display a Google Map inside a polymer element.

This map should be handled from outside of my component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to declare a simple custom element that contains a google map. In this example the map has to be handled manually outside of the component :

- **gmap.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="gmap-map">
  <template>
    <div id='mapView' style='height: 500px; width: 500px'></div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="gmap.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

- **gmap.dart**

```dart
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('gmap-map')
class MapElement extends PolymerElement {
  GMap map;

  MapElement.created() : super.created() {
    final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
      ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
    final mapView = getShadowRoot('gmap-map').querySelector("#mapView");
    map = new GMap(mapView, mapOptions);
  }

  attached() {
    super.attached();

    // this allow to notify the map that the size of the canvas has changed.
    // in some cases, the map behaves like it has a 0*0 size.
    event.trigger(map, 'resize', []);
  }
}
```

Now you can use it in an html file like that (you access the map instance with the `map` getter on element) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GMaps app</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="gmap.html">
    <script type="application/dart">
import 'dart:html';
import 'gmap.dart' as m;
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
main(){
  initPolymer();
  m.MapElement mapElement = querySelector('#myMap');
  mapElement.map
    ..panTo(new LatLng(48, 2.5))
    ..zoom = 5;
}
    </script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Gmaps</h1>
    <gmap-map id='myMap'></gmap-map>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for Dartium as advertised, but what I find strange, is if I use "pub serve" and browse using Chrome/Firefox to a page using google maps, with the javascript put in the Polymer Element itself, just above the dart import, it works, but this doesn't in Dartium, when not run through "pub serve".  Would that have something to do with how the code is compiled in "pub build/serve"??

Answer (score 3):

Google has now created a Google Maps (Polymer) web component:

- http://polymerlabs.github.io/google-map/
- https://github.com/PolymerLabs/google-map

Usage can be as simple as:

```html
<google-map latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942"></google-map>
```

Also see Eric Bidelman's brief (~9m) talk on Polymer, where he works through using this component: http://youtu.be/eORqFaf_QzM?t=1m30s

Comment: I included 'google_maps: any' in the yaml-file, and got the packages. Where do I find the html-file to import into the custom element?